# Drop rows in Pandas Series with condition on label

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas Series that looks like that:

```
0.000000        41.449176
15000.000000    28.468407
14999.000000    22.355769
7000.000000      2.369505
14990.000000     1.476648
10000.000000     0.721154
4900.000000      0.583791
4500.000000      0.377747
4999.000000      0.343407
14900.000000     0.274725
14500.000000     0.206044
4990.000000      0.206044
5000.000000      0.206044
3010.000000      0.171703
9999.000000      0.171703
16000.000000     0.137363
15100.000000     0.103022
50000.000000     0.068681
8000.000000      0.068681
900.000000       0.034341
4998.000000      0.034341
6000.000000      0.034341
20000.000000     0.034341
150000.000000    0.034341
12000.000000     0.034341
1500.000000      0.034341
Name: limit, dtype: float64
```

How can I remove rows from this Series where label > 15000?

I know how to remove single rows using Series.drop(15000). But I have no idea how to remove rows using conditions to lables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with change logic - get all rows with `<= 15000` in labels (index):

```
s[s.index <= 15000]
```

Comment: Is this not duplicated?

Comment: @ansev - give me link, please

Answer (score 1):

you can also use [`callable`](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/indexing.html#selection-by-callable)

```
s.loc[lambda x: x.index<=15000]
```

or

```
s[lambda x: x.index<=15000]
```